# How to notify parent about change in child component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component with this template:

```
<p *ngIf="user != null" >
    Id: {{user.id}}<br>
    Name: {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}<br>
    Nick: {{user.nickname}}<br>
    Gender: {{user.gender}}<br>
    Birthday: {{user.birthday}}<br>
    Last login: {{user.lastUpdateDate}}<br>
    Registered: {{user.registrationDate}}<br>
</p>
```

I get user from server using http request, so when data is loaded, user is shown.

How can I notify parent component that data was loaded and shown?

Comment: What do you mean by parent?

Comment: Using an output. See https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs. `<child (contentHasChanged)="doSomething()">`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply by using `EventEmitter` in child component (this example works with click event, you can emit the event whenever you want to).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="changeState(State.FINISHED)">Finish</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() stateChanged = new EventEmitter<State>();

  changeState(state: State) {
    this.stateChanged.emit(state);
    ...
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <child-component
      (stateChanged)="onStateChange($event)">
    </child-component>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  onStateChange(state: State) {
    ...
  }
}
```

When you click on the `Finish` button, it calls the `changeState` method, where the `stateChange` event is emited. It can be listened to as seen in parent component's template. This will call the `onStateChange` method where you react to the event however you want to.

See
[Component Interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)
article in [Angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/) for more info

Comment: just a small remark regarding the naming. The convention in the [Angular coding style guide - Don't prefix output properties](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#dont-prefix-output-properties) is that the output is named without 'on', so in this case it's gonna be "statusChanged" and the handler "onStatusChanged()".

Comment: @bokkie I updated the answer, good catch.